# How to enable javascript function window.open() in PyQt5 Python browser

Tags: python-3.x, webview, pyqt5

I'm developing a web browser in Python and PyQt5. The browser is working fine but new tab and javascript window.open() is not working. I want to know how to enable new tab and popup functions. javascript alert() function is working but new window and new tab is not working.

If you could help me then I'll be very thankful to you.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets           # +++ QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage,QWebEngineSettings


class Ui_MainWindow(object): 
    def back(self):    self.webView.back() 
    def forword(self): self.webView.forward() 
    def reload(self):  self.webView.reload()
    def stop(self):  self.webView.stop()
    def newtab(self):  self.QWebEnginePage.OpenLinkInNewTab()

    def createWindow(self, windowType):
        if windowType == QWebEnginePage.WebBrowserTab:
            self.webView = Ui_MainWindow()
            self.webView.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)
            self.webView.show()
            return self.webView
        return super(Ui_MainWindow, self).createWindow(windowType)

    def home(self):
        self.webView.load(QtCore.QUrl("http://pyxisad.com"))
        QWebEnginePage.JavascriptCanOpenWindows:True
    def search(self):

        url = self.ln_addressbar.text()
        self.webView.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        QWebEnginePage.JavascriptCanOpenWindows:True
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("PyxisAd")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tb_back = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.tb_back.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 41, 31))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icons/back.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.tb_back.setIcon(icon)
        self.tb_back.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(32, 32))
        self.tb_back.setObjectName("tb_back")
        ############### Event #############################
        self.tb_back.clicked.connect(self.back)
        ##################################################
        self.tb_reload = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.tb_reload.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 20, 41, 31))
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icons/reload.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.tb_reload.setIcon(icon1)
        self.tb_reload.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(32, 32))
        self.tb_reload.setObjectName("tb_reload")
        ############### Event #############################3
        self.tb_reload.clicked.connect(self.reload)
        ##################################################
        self.tb_forword_2 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.tb_forword_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 20, 41, 31))
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icons/forword.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.tb_forword_2.setIcon(icon2)
        self.tb_forword_2.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(32, 32))
        self.tb_forword_2.setObjectName("tb_forword_2")
        ############### Event #############################3
        self.tb_forword_2.clicked.connect(self.forword)
        ##################################################
        self.tb_home = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.tb_home.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 20, 41, 31))
        icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icons/home.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.tb_home.setIcon(icon3)
        self.tb_home.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(32, 32))
        self.tb_home.setObjectName("tb_home")
        ############### Event #############################3
        self.tb_home.clicked.connect(self.home)
        ##################################################
        self.ln_addressbar = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.ln_addressbar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 20, 491, 31))
        self.ln_addressbar.setObjectName("ln_addressbar")
        self.ln_addressbar.setPlaceholderText("Enter URL..")

        self.tb_search = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.tb_search.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 20, 41, 31))
        icon4 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon4.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icons/search.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.tb_search.setIcon(icon4)
        self.tb_search.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(32, 32))
        self.tb_search.setObjectName("tb_search")
        ############### Event #############################3
        self.tb_search.clicked.connect(self.search)
        #self.tb_search.returnPressed.connect(self.search)
        ##################################################

        self.webView = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self.centralwidget) # + QWebEngineView

        self.webView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 60, 1400, 700))
        self.webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("about:blank"))
        self.webView.setObjectName("webView")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        ############### Event #############################
        #self.newtab.clicked.connect(createWindow())

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("PyxisAd", "PyxisAd"))
        self.tb_back.setText(_translate("PyxisAd", "back"))
        self.tb_reload.setText(_translate("PyxisAd", "reload"))
        self.tb_forword_2.setText(_translate("PyxisAd", "forword"))
        self.tb_home.setText(_translate("PyxisAd", "home"))
        self.tb_search.setText(_translate("PyxisAd", "search"))   



if __name__ == "__main__": 
    import sys 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) 
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow() 
    ui = Ui_MainWindow() 
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow) 
    MainWindow.show() 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: [QWebEnginePage.createWindow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#createWindow).

Comment: I don't know how to use this function